# Programmatically hiding/unhiding status Bar in iOS 8 without animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attempting to hide/unhide the status bar programmatically upon a view appearing and disappearing. This was my first attempt (that worked), but it animates my UINavigationBar which I don't want to happen.

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

But this is essentially what I want to work, but it does absolutely nothing.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` you should return `UIStatusBarAnimationNone` from

```
- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation
```

and call

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Complete code:

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL visible;

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return self.visible;
}

- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationNone;
}

- (void)setVisible:(BOOL)visible {
    _visible = visible;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.visible = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.visible = NO;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: okay I am getting it to hide, but the biggest problem is that my navigation bar is being animated when the status bar is hidden/unhidden, causing my whole screen to shift up about 20 pixels while animating to and from my view controller.

Answer (score 0):

just add a simple line and your problem will solved.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:status];
```